# How does presentViewController display the view?

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm curious as to what the presentViewController does with the first parameter, ***imagePickerController***. Given the way I assigned imagePickerController's properties, will the presentViewController use all that information to display the view?

```
@IBAction func imageFromPhotoLibrary(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // Hide the keyboard.
    myTextField.resignFirstResponder()

    // UIImagePickerController is a view controller that lets a user pick media from their photo library.
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

    // Only allow photos to be picked, not taken.
    imagePickerController.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

    // Make sure ViewController is notified when the user picks an image.
    imagePickerController.delegate = self

    presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`presentViewController` won't use any of the options.  The `imagePickerController` you passed in will use those options.

Since the Apple APIs are pretty well designed, `presentViewController` does one thing (SRP), and does exactly what it says it does... *presents the view controller* you pass it.

The `imagePickerController` is in charge *controlling* the *view* of the image picker.

Comment: Okay, gotcha. If I changed my sourceType to .Camera instead,  presentViewController will just present the information given by imagePickerController, which now controls the view to bring up the camera?

Comment: It's like addChild(button) which only adds the button, but doesn't do anything to the button other than display the looks of it?